# Javascript JSONArray issue with push() and for loop

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object, for-loop

I've made a simple program to store locally an array using two for loops, but something strange took place...

There's my code:

```
var imagesdata = data[0];
var preferences = data[1];

for (var i = preferences.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    (function(i){
        for (var z = imagesdata.length - 1; z >= 0; z--) {
            (function(i){
                if(imagesdata[z].cathegory == preferences[i].cathegory){
                    var array = $('body').data('data'+preferences[i].cathegory);
                    if(array == null){
                        alert('asefsef');
                        $('body').data('data'+preferences[i].cathegory, [{'pname' : imagesdata[z].pname , 'pimage' : imagesdata[z].pimage}]);
                    }else{
                        $('body').data('data'+preferences[i].cathegory, array.push({'pname' : imagesdata[z].pname , 'pimage' : imagesdata[z].pimage}));
                    }
                }
            })(i);
        };
    })(i);
};
```

**It says that object 2 has no method push** But why number two appears on the array if I've just inserted : `[{'pname' : imagesdata[z].pname , 'pimage' : imagesdata[z].pimage}]`

Thanks!

Comment: It does not look like it has anything to do with JSON.

Comment: Why do you need those closures?  'i' would remain the same on each iteration of the secondary for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push()` returns the length of the array, not the array with the new element tacked on.

Unless I'm mis-reading your code:

1. In the first iteration, you're hitting the `== null` check, and so creating a new array.
2. In the second iteration, you're in the `else` clause and adding an element to the array, *but* then setting the `data` property to it's length (2).
3. In the *third* iteration, a `Number` does not have a `push()` method.

However, note that because the `array` variable will be a reference to the array once you've initialized the array, all changes you make to it will *automagically* be reflected back in the `data` property; so you don't need to write back the changes when you `push()` new data:

```
if (array == null) {
    alert('asefsef');
    $('body').data('data' + preferences[i].cathegory, [{
        'pname': imagesdata[z].pname,
        'pimage': imagesdata[z].pimage}]);
} else {
    array.push({
        'pname': imagesdata[z].pname,
        'pimage': imagesdata[z].pimage
    });
}​
```

FYI, you're probably only hitting the `== null` check by luck. `data()` returns `undefined` if the key doesn't exist, and it just so happens `undefined == null` is `true` (through type coercion). A better check would be `=== undefined`, or better yet, `array instanceof Array`

Comment: Oh... What a mistake haha :) Thanks a lot!